# Javascript - .sort() does not have an affect on larger numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to sort out an array that is being returned from least to greatest. I am attempting to achieve this by using the `.sort()` method. The sort method seems to be working exactly as expected when the numbers are less then a million, but has no affect when the numbers are larger then that.

I am expecting a sort array from least to greatest regardless of the number amount such as:

```
let topArr = [
            { sales: "28,883",  store: "Appointments" },
            { sales: "1,432,883", store: "Walk in" },
            { sales: "1,494,927", store: "Online" },
            { sales: "2,248,883",  store: "Retail Stores" },                      
        ];
```

Here is an example of the sort method not working on larger numbers

```js
let topArr = [
            { sales: "1,494,927", store: "Online" },
            { sales: "2,248,883",  store: "Retail Stores" },
            { sales: "1,432,883", store: "Walk in" },
            { sales: "28,883",  store: "Appointments" },
        ];
        
        
topArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseInt(a.sales.replace("/,/g","")) - parseInt(b.sales.replace("/,/g",""));
 });
 
 console.log(topArr)
```

Here is an example of the sort method working as expected with smaller numbers:

```js
let topArr = [
            { sales: "494,927", store: "Online" },
            { sales: "48,883",  store: "Retail Stores" },
            { sales: "432,883", store: "Walk in" },
            { sales: "28,883",  store: "Appointments" },
        ];
        
        
topArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseInt(a.sales.replace("/,/g","")) - parseInt(b.sales.replace("/,/g",""));
 });
 
 console.log(topArr)
```

Comment: Don't use `.replace("/,/g","")`, use `.replace(/,/g,"")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need regular expressions

```
/,/g
```

not a string which looks like a regular expression.

```js
let topArr = [
            { sales: "1,494,927", store: "Online" },
            { sales: "2,248,883",  store: "Retail Stores" },
            { sales: "1,432,883", store: "Walk in" },
            { sales: "28,883",  store: "Appointments" },
        ];
        
        
topArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.sales.replace(/,/g,"") - b.sales.replace(/,/g,"");
 });
 
 console.log(topArr)
```

Comment: Which is just a typo...